# Exception throw by my custom Add Row code

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my jTable the first column holds a numerical value. The next row when I select "Add Row" runs this code:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
int x = jTable1.getRowCount();
String cellValue = "";
if(x > 0){
    java.lang.Object cell = jTable1.getValueAt(x,0); 
    int a = Integer.parseInt(cell.toString());
    int b = a + 1;
    cellValue = Integer.toString(b);
}

java.lang.Object[] os = new Object[]{cellValue,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",};
model.addRow(os);
jTable1.setModel(model);
jTable1.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(true);
```

The point of this code is to add a new row, but the first value in the new row will be filled out. this is the key number. Unfortunately, the key number is not related to the number of Rows.

When the jButton to "Add Row" is pressed, it throws this Exception.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 837 >= 837

The number is meaningful as 837 is the number of rows the jTable had when i pushed the button.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It is quite clear what its saying its expecting a number smaller than 837 i.e. 836... also whats up with the "",}; at the end.

Comment: Also it looks like a really bad way to do what you are trying to do - what API are you using?

Comment: I'm fairly new at jTables. This code above was just my best shot at it.
What I want to do is get the value from Column 0 of the last row on the Jtable add 1 to it and then put that value into the first column of the new row.

Answer (score 0):

This maps to [Vector.size()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#size%28%29) in [DefaultTableModel](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel-source.html):

```
int x = jTable1.getRowCount();
```

And this maps to [Vector.get(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#get%28int%29):

```
java.lang.Object cell = jTable1.getValueAt(x,0);
```

Taking a closer look at [Vector.get(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#get%28int%29) reveals:

> Throws: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size()).

Now since `x == size()` the Exception is thrown.

This should fix the issue:

```
java.lang.Object cell = jTable1.getValueAt(--x,0);
```